# How to control the method scope?

Tags: ruby

I abstract my question to the following situation.

```
# /somewhere/build_ability/car.rb
module BuildAbility
  module Car
    def build_car
      build_component
    end

    def build_component
      # Specific designed for build car, not common used
      # Totally different from build_component in BuildAbility::Ship
    end
  end
end

# /somewhere/build_ability/ship.rb
module BuildAbility
  module Ship
    def build_ship
      build_component
    end

    def build_component
      # Specific designed for build ship, not common used
      # Totally different from build_component in BuildAbility::Car
    end
  end
end

# /somewhere/omni_factory.rb
class OmniFactory
  include BuildAbility::Car
  include BuildAbility::Ship

  def build_component
    # common used method
  end
end
```

The purpose of include `BuildAbility::Car` to `OmniFactory` is to introduce `build_car`, and not want to introduce `build_component`.

The `build_component` in `BuildAbility::Car` is specific designed for `build_car`, it just only work for `build_car`, and no use in other place.  So when `OmniFactory` include `BuildAbility::Car`, there is no need to introduce `build_component`.

Same situation in `BuildAbility::Ship`.

**So where should I put the `build_component` in `car.rb` to achieve the purpose?**

I thought this may offen happened in gems, the gem may not want some low-level basic functions exposed to users, and only used in gem files.

The following code is one of the solution, something like closure, but I thought this way is too ugly, is there some other solution?

```
# /somewhere/build_ability/car.rb
module BuildAbility
  module Car
    build_component = lambda {
      # Specific designed for build car, not common used
      # Totally different from build_component in BuildAbility::Ship
    }

    define_method :build_car do
      build_component.call
    end
  end
end

# /somewhere/build_ability/ship.rb
module BuildAbility
  module Ship
    build_component = lambda {
      # Specific designed for build ship, not common used
      # Totally different from build_component in BuildAbility::Car
    }

    define_method :build_ship do
      build_component.call
    end
  end
end

# /somewhere/omni_factory.rb
class OmniFactory
  include BuildAbility::Car
  include BuildAbility::Ship

  def build_component
    # common used method
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have `build_component` as a module method, which will not be inherited when you `include` the module.

Here's a working example:

```
# /somewhere/build_ability/car.rb
module BuildAbility
  module Car
    def build_car
      Car.build_component
    end
    def self.build_component
      p "car"
    end
  end
end

# /somewhere/build_ability/ship.rb
module BuildAbility
  module Ship
    def build_ship
      Ship.build_component
    end
    def self.build_component
      p "ship"
    end
  end
end

# /somewhere/omni_factory.rb
class OmniFactory
  include BuildAbility::Car
  include BuildAbility::Ship

  def build_component
    p "omnifactory"
    # common used method
  end
end

OmniFactory.new.build_component
OmniFactory.new.build_car
OmniFactory.new.build_ship
```

This outputs:

```
"omnifactory"
"car"
"ship"
```

In this way, the `OmniFactory`'s `build_component` method does not interfere with anything. Moreover, the `self.build_component` method from `BuildAbility::Car` will not be included in the `OmniFactory`.

Another way to do this (a bit dirtier), is having the `build_component` be a member of a class.

```
# /somewhere/build_ability/car.rb
module BuildAbility
  module Car
    def build_car
      CarStrategy.build_component
    end

    class CarStrategy
      def self.build_component
        p "car"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However, to me, this solution looks not as straightforward and simple as the module method one.